reduce lldb output when single-stepping
When I am using lldb to debug a 'c' program (at the command line), I often like to break at a statement, and then single step through the code to see what is happening.  With gdb, I can just keep typing 'n', and see the next line.  With lldb, every time I type 'n', I see "frame #0", (the values of the variable in the function call), which takes up dozens of lines and makes it very difficult to actually see the program flow (because the stack frame keeps separating each line of code).
Is there a way to turn that off, and simply see the next line of code?

What does lldb's documentation say, and why does it help you?

Just from help n, we get a bunch of options, but at the bottom, it says 'n' is an abbreviation for 'thread step-over'. Also, it supports -C <python-class> for "scripted step". Doing help thread step-over. So, thread -C my_python_class step-scripted may allow you to intervene. Obviously, you'll want to create a "macro" that does this (e.g. nq for "quiet n mode"). But ...

If that fails, there may be an external way to filter this. A similar question I just answered: In Linux (POSIX), how to forward stdin to forked child process while inspect the content? gives some links to other answers of mine for using LD_PRELOAD, pipes, pseudo-TTY (pty), for injecting input and filtering output. To my mind, the least intrusive for your case would be to write a C program (e.g. mylldb) that mimics lldb, but runs the "real" lldb under a PTY that you control. If you see n, send it, and filter the subsequent output.

You can turn off the thread info printing with:
settings set thread-stop-format ""

You can control how many source lines lldb prints on stop with the stop-line-count-before and stop-line-count-after settings, but lldb treats both these values being 0 to mean "don't show line info" so at present the best you can do is the stop line and one line before or after.

This started me on the right path.  I needed settings set frame-stop-format, not thread-stop-format.

If you end up having more than one style that you like, you might have a look at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/lldb/examples/python/disassembly_mode.py - that command switches between a "source friendly" and a "disassembly friendly" stepping view (by my lights...) but it could be easily extended to support other modes.
